# How do I hide the windows terminal from a cmd file

Tags: windows-10, command-line, display, terminal

I have this in my startup folder "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Element.lnk " as a cmd file. I wanted to know how to make the terminal not display visually.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, the best is to set a `@echo off` at the beginning of your batch file.

---

However this is a question a fast google search could have answered as well, so the next time you have a question you should do some research first. We are always happy to help with arising issues, but in order to get answers, your question mustn’t get closed, and if it does not contain what you have tried so far, it probably will.

Comment: `echo` hides the commands being shown; it usually doesn't hide the console window itself, does it?

Comment: Well, usually if nothing is displayed, there is no console window that opens. Or at least that is the case with all the things I fire up at startup using the startup folder and Task Scheduler